# Show primary key column in table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, primary-key

i have the following query

```
    use  RecipesExample;

    SELECT Recipes.RecipeTitle

    FROM Recipes
```

The create table is:

```
CREATE TABLE Recipes (
        RecipeID int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
        RecipeTitle nvarchar (255) NULL ,
        RecipeClassID smallint NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
        Preparation text NULL ,
        Notes text NULL
);

ALTER TABLE Recipes 
        ADD CONSTRAINT Recipes_PK PRIMARY KEY 
        (
                RecipeID
        );
```

Which outputs:

[image]

How do I edit the query so I can also view the primary key? And also the foreign key RecipeClassID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add required columns in your query comma separated,

```
SELECT Recipes.RecipeID,Recipes.RecipeClassID,Recipes.RecipeTitle FROM Recipes
```

Answer (score 0):

use like below

```
 SELECT Recipes.RecipeID, Recipes.RecipeTitle
```